# Prototype with Principle: Before/after masking effect on drag

Tags: animation, prototyping, principle-app

Has anyone tried to do something similar with Principle (animation tool)?

- images need to cover/uncover with masking effect
- animation works on drag

[image: Example: https://www.iesede.com/]

Example: https://www.iesede.com/

Is that even possible to do with Principle?

Comment: I've not really tried Principle so I won't be answering the question, but the dragging is just a mouse event and not really animation. You should maybe mention in the question what kind of event you want to trigger this "cover/uncover" and if it should follow mouse or not. That seems the most crucial part. Maybe you just want a hover to reveal the second image in a similar way. I'm thinking perhaps 2 images on top of each other and the top one's width is animated on hover or something like that.

Comment: I didn't look at the website code, but I'm thinking I would do something like this outside of Principle: 2 elements one with the bird photo and the other one with the code bird. Both of the elements are animated to bob up and down. Then you just reveal the code bird as is your want. Perhaps [something like this](https://jsfiddle.net/lollero/9e0g4jvh/).

Comment: Thank you for your comment, but I was looking for specific solution in Principle app. If somebody faces similar issue, here is the answer: https://www.reddit.com/r/userexperience/comments/arv3vr/prototype_with_principle_beforeafter_masking/